# Core Data - Save selected tableview rows

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios7

I am new to iOS programming, so forgive me my incompetence.

I'm trying to find a solution to save selected rows from tableview that gets data from Songlist entity that holds all the songs names and has no relationships - to another entity called Song.

I've searched this site and google and tried many things I found but I still can't figure this out by myself.

I managed to save the songs to Song entity but the problem at the moment is the songs are saved at the moment user selects the cell - but I'd like to save selected rows when user presses save button.

And the Song entity has relationship as you can probably see - its called songConcert.

SongList entity has 2 attributes: songName and albumName;
Song entity has 3 attributes: songName, albumName and relationship songsConcert (to Concert entity)

Here is the code from my SongsTableViewController where user selects rows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

[theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



    // Reflect selection in data model

    Song *newSong = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    addSong = newSong;
    newSong.songName = cell.textLabel.text;
    newSong.albumName = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    addSong.songConcert = songsConcert;


} else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // Reflect deselection in data model

}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {



   NSError *error = nil;
if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) { //save failed
        NSLog(@"Save Failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Save Succseeded");
    }

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: You are using the method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method... This method is executed when your user taps the row (or did select row at index path). What you might think about is how to accumulate data for each selected row, and include that accumulated data in a method that is fired when your user hits the Save button (e.g. `- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender`)... Let me know if you still require assistance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip. I actually tried to use NSMutableArray to store selected items but did something wrong I guess. I post the code here after weekend so you can check what I did wrong.

Comment: A tip for new players... don't forget to init your `NSMutableArray`! As a newcomer to programming and Objective-C I often forgot this task. For example: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mutArray;` then `NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` - refer also [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) although the convenience method `initWithArray` is missing form this page. (Bug logged.)

Comment: That was it probably, I didn't init my NSMutable Array :) I'll try that again and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much - I figured it out - everything works as expected now

Comment: Happy to be able to help.